# How to get List datasource from One to Another Component

Tags: blazor

I have two component in blazor.First component contain Country datasource (list datasource) .I would like to know how to get"Country datasource" from first component to second component.please check the below code and advise how to do this.

First Component :-

```
    @code{
    public List<CountryMaster> Countries { get; set; }
    public SfGrid<Order> Grid { get; set; }
    public int CurrentViewRecordCount { get; set; }

 protected override void OnInitialized()
    {


        Countries = Enumerable.Range(1, 75).Select(x => new CountryMaster()
        {
            CountryID = 1000 + x,
            CountryName = (new string[] { "USA", "UK", "CHINA", "RUSSIA", "INDIA" })[new Random().Next(5)],
            
        }).ToList();
    }

public class CountryMaster
    {
        public int? CountryID { get; set; }
        public string CountryName { get; set; }

    }

}
```

Comment: please help to solve this

Comment: Where is your second component and what is its relation to the first one?

Comment: You need to explain more clearly what you are trying to do, as it's not obvious at the moment. Also, it looks like you are trying to break the way Blazor works. In general, components should be standalone, and not rely on data from other components. You can pass data from a parent to a child via a parameter, but if you're using a child or sibling component as a data source (which is what it looks like) you're probably doing it wrong. However, without a much clearer explanation of what you're trying to achieve, this is just speculation.